# Can't attach a UIScrollView Paging in storyboards iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, scroll-paging

I have a tabled application built with storyboards, so I would like to add a paging possibility for the items in table. I used [this tutorial](http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/03/uiscrollview-paging/):

So I added the new view to the storyboard and the UIScrollView on the view. Than made a property UIScrollView* scrollView; and make the relation scrollView - ECOMClPanelPagingViewController in storyboard. (ECOMClPanelPagingViewController is a UIViewController class for my view.

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ECOMClPanelPagingViewController : UIViewController
{
    UIScrollView *scrollView;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView* scrollView;
@end
```

.m

```
#import "ECOMClPanelPagingViewController.h"
@interface ECOMClPanelPagingViewController ()
@end
@implementation ECOMClPanelPagingViewController
@synthesize scrollView;
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor redColor], [UIColor greenColor], [UIColor blueColor], nil];
    for (int i = 0; i < colors.count; i++) {
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;
        UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        subview.backgroundColor = [colors objectAtIndex:i];
        [self.scrollView addSubview:subview];
        [subview release];
    }
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width * colors.count, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
}
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    self.scrollView = nil;
}
- (void)dealloc
{
    [scrollView release];
    [super dealloc];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
@end
```

So I see only the white background with navigation controller.. Who can help me with it?

Answer (score 1):

Just need to uncheck the Use Autolayout option